# C++ - Efficient way to group double vectors following a certain criteria

Tags: c++, list, vector, grouping

I have a list of objects saved in a CSV-like file using the following scheme:

[value11],...,[value1n],[label1]

[value21],...,[value2n],[label2]

...

[valuen1],...,[valuenn],[labeln]

(each line is a single object, i.e. a vector of doubles and the respective label).
I would like to collect them in groups with a certain custom criteria (i.e. same values at n-th and (n+1)-th position of all objects of that group). And i need to do that in the most efficient way, since the text file contains hundreds of thounsands of objects. I'm using the C++ programming language.

To do so, firstly I load all the CSV lines in a simple custom container (with getObject, getLabel and import methods). Then i use the following code to read them and make groups. "verifyGroupRequirements" is a function which returns true if the group conditions are satisfied, false otherwise.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < ObjectsList.getSize(); ++i) {
  MyObject currentObj;
  currentObj.attributes = ObjectsList.getObject(i);
  currentObj.label = ObjectsList.getLabel(i);

  if (i == 0) {
    // Sequence initialization with the first object
    ObjectsGroup currentGroup = ObjectsGroup();

    currentGroup.objectsList.push_back(currentObj);
    tmpGroupList.push_back(currentGroup);
  } else {
    // if it is not the first pattern, then we check sequence conditions
    list<ObjectsGroup>::iterator it5;

    for (it5 = tmpGroupList.begin(); it5 != tmpGroupList.end(); ++it5) {
      bool AddObjectToGroupRequirements =
        verifyGroupRequirements(it5->objectsList.back(), currentObj) & 
        ( (it5->objectsList.size() < maxNumberOfObjectsPerGroup) |
        (maxNumberOfObjectsPerGroup == 0) );

      if (AddObjectToGroupRequirements) {
        // Object added to the group
        it5->objectsList.push_back(currentObj);

        break;
      } else {
        // If we can't find a group which satisfy those conditions and we
        // arrived at the end of the list of groups, then we create a new
        // group with that object.
        size_t gg = std::distance(it5, tmpGroupList.end());

        if (gg == 1) {
          ObjectsGroup tmp1 = ObjectsGroup();
          tmp1.objectsList.push_back(currentObj);

          tmpGroupList.push_back(tmp1);

          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (maxNumberOfObjectsPerGroup > 0) {
    // With a for loop we can take all the elements of 
    // tmpGroupList which have reached the maximum size
    list<ObjectsGroup>::iterator it2;

    for (it2 = tmpGroupList.begin(); it2 != tmpGroupList.end(); ++it2) {
      if (it2->objectsList.size() == maxNumberOfObjectsPerGroup)
        finalGroupList.push_back(*it2);
    }

    // Since tmpGroupList is a list we can use remove_if to remove them
    tmpGroupList.remove_if(rmCondition);
  }
}

if (maxNumberOfObjectsPerGroup == 0) 
  finalGroupList = vector<ObjectsGroup> (tmpGroupList.begin(), tmpGroupList.end());
else {
  list<ObjectsGroup>::iterator it6;

  for (it6 = tmpGroupList.begin(); it6 != tmpGroupList.end(); ++it6)
    finalGroupList.push_back(*it6);
}
```

Where tmpGroupList is a `list<MyObject>`, finalGroupList is a `vector<MyObject>` and rmCondition is a boolean function that returns true if the size of a ObjectsGroup is bigger than a fixed value. MyObject and ObjectsGroup are two simple data structures, written in the following way:

```
// Data structure of the single object
class MyObject {
  public:
    MyObject(
          unsigned short int &spaceToReserve,
          double &defaultContent,
          string &lab) {

      attributes = vector<double>(spaceToReserve, defaultContent);
      label = lab;
    }
    vector<double> attributes;
    string label;
};

// Data structure of a group of object
class ObjectsGroup {
  public:
    list<MyObject> objectsList;
    double health;
};
```

This code seems to work, but it is really slow. Since, as i said before, i have to apply it on a large set of objects, is there a way to improve it and make it faster? Thanks.

[EDIT] What I'm trying to achieve is to make groups of objects where each object is a `vector<double>` (got from a CSV file). So what I'm asking here is, is there a more efficient way to collect those kind of objects in groups than what is exposed in the code example above?

[EDIT2] I need to make groups using all of those vectors.

Comment: In your `for ( it5...` loop, you're using bitwise `&` and `|`, rather than boolean `&&` and `||`. Is that really what you want?

Comment: @stefan From a theoretical C++ point of view i think the correct way is using the boolean operators `&&` and `||` in this case (correct me if I'm wrong), but from a practical point of view I can't see any performance difference between them (at least in this example).

Comment: my comment wasn't aiming at a potential performance problem but rather at general code quality. In my opinion, code should always express intent. In this case, operating on boolean values shouldn't be done with bitwise operations.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm reading your question...

> ... I would like to collect them in groups with a certain custom
>   criteria (i.e. same values at n-th and (n+1)-th position of all
>   objects of that group) ...

Ok, I read this part, and kept on reading...

> ... And i need to do that in the most efficient way, since the text file
>   contains hundreds of thounsands of objects...

I'm still with you, makes perfect sense.

> ... To do so, firstly I load all the CSV lines ...

{thud} {crash} {loud explosive noises}

Ok, I stopped reading right there, and didn't pay much attention to the rest of the question, including the large code sample. This is because we have a basic problem right from the start:

1) You say that your intention is, typically, to read only a small
portion of this huge CSV file, and...

2) ... to do that you load the entire CSV file, into a fairly sophisticated data structure.

These two statements are at odds with each. You're reading a huge number of values from a file. You are creating an object for each value. Based on the premise of your question, you're going to have a large number of these objects. But then, when all is said and done, you're only going to look at a small number of them, and throw the rest away?

You are doing a lot of work, presumably using up a lot of memory, and CPU cycles, loading a huge data set, only to ignore most of it. And you are wondering why you're having performance issues? Seems pretty cut and dry to me.

What would be an alternative way of doing this? Well, let's turn this whole problem inside out, and approach it piecemeal. Let's read a CSV file, one line at a time, parse the values in the CSV-formatted file, and pass the resulting strings to a lambda.

Something like this:

```
template<typename Callback> void parse_csv_lines(std::ifstream &i,
                                                 Callback &&callback)
{
    std::string line;

    while (1)
    {
        line.clear();
        std::getline(i, line);

        // Deal with missing newline on the last line...

        if (i.eof() && line.empty())
             break;

        std::vector<std::string> words;

        // At this point, you'll take this "line", and split it apart, at
        // the commas, into the individual words. Parsing a CSV-
        // formatted file. Not very exciting, you're doing this
        // already, the algorithm is boring to implement, you know
        // how to do it, so let's say you replace this entire comment
        // with your boiler-plate CSV parsing logic from your existing
        // code

        callback(words);
    }
}
```

Ok, now we've done that task of parsing the CSV file. Now, let's say we want to do the task you've set out in the beginning of your question, grab every nth and n+1th position. So...

```
void do_something_with_n_and_nplus1_words(size_t n)
{
    std::ifstream input_file("input_file.csv");

    // Insert code to check if input_file.is_open(), and if not, do
    // whatever

    parse_csv_lines(input_file,
                    [n]
                    (const auto &words)
                    {
                       // So now, grab words[n] and words[n+1]
                       // (after checking, of course, for a malformed
                       // CSV file with fewer than "n+2" values)
                       // and do whatever you want with them.
                    });
}
```

That's it. Now, you end up simply reading the CSV file, and doing the absolute minimum amount of work required to extract the nth and the n+1th values from each CSV file. It's going to be fairly difficult to come up with an approach that does less work (except, of course, micro-optimizations related to CSV parsing, and word buffers; or perhaps foregoing the overhead of `std::ifstream`, but rather mmap-ing the entire file, and then parsing it out by scanning its mmap-ed contents, something like that), I'd think.

For other similar one-off tasks, requiring only a small number of values from the CSV files, just write an appropriate lambda to fetch them out.

Perhaps, you need to retrieve two or more subsets of values from the large CSV file, and you want to read the CSV file once, maybe? Well, hard to give the best general approach. Each one of these situations will require individual analysis, to pick the best approach.

Comment: Hi, every line of the CSV file is a double vector and i need to collect all of them in groups following a certain criteria. So i'm not loading the whole dataset to process just a little part of it.

Comment: This is in conflict with the actual question: "I load all the CSV lines". That's what you wrote.

Comment: I talked about the CSV just to let you understand the layout of data I'm loading. So think about those vectors as completely loaded in memory, then i would like to make groups with all of them. For instance: line1 has values 10 and 5 in the first and second attribute and line7 has the same values at the same position, so i put them in a container. The code example i showed above works, but it is not efficient i suppose.

Comment: Before assuming that your performance issues are with accessing the data, you should actually verify that, and obtain some runtime profiling data: how long it takes to read the entire CSV file into memory, versus how long it takes to access the data that you're looking for.

Comment: It takes 7 seconds to load the whole dataset from the CSV file (about 400000 lines). I simply save them in a `std::vector< std::vector<double> >`. Then I run the code above, which is slower, as it takes 30 seconds for just the first 1000 objects. Since the list of groups grows while scanning the dataset, the complexity rises. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You'll need to do more profiling. For example:  "MyObject currentObj; currentObj.attributes=ObjectsList.getObject(i); currentObj.label=ObjectsList.getLabel(i);" looks like this makes copies of several objects. Later, this whole thing gets push_back()-ed -- another copy takes place. Copying large objects is obviously expensive. Instead of using objects directly, consider a redesign using smart pointers (std::shared_ptr), so the analogous code just ends up moving a few smart pointers, and incrementing a reference count. I'd expect this will be much faster than copying large objects.

Comment: Thanks, I'll study how to use smart pointers. Do you think could help the begin/end implementations inside the ObjectsList class using iterators to work on it?